# How many possible ways are there to print 125 pages on 5 printers?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

I think I understand this problem but I want to make sure I do get it thoroughly. In my mind, this problem is asking you to assign a single page to a single printer, but it doesn't really matter the order in which they are printed. I.E., we don't care if page 1 is sent to printer 1 first, or if printer one gets page 2 first and then page 1 is sent.

In my mind, then, we would simply take a page and say, how many choices do I have to print it? That would be 5 for the 1st page. Now page 2 also has 5 choices, and so on and so on, so that means the solution would be `5 x 5 x ... x 5 = 5 ^ 125`.

Is this the correct answer or am I implicitly slipping in order some how and need to remove the number of permutations from this number? Thanks for your help in understanding this problem!

Comment: You think correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so it seems that my original thinking is indeed the correct answer as if you choose to start with page 2, then go to page 3, etc., etc., until you wrap back around and finish with page 1, there are still the same number of ways to distribute all the pages to each printer as if you had started with page 1. Therefore `5 ^ 125` is the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I think there are 2 ways to think about this, since the problem itself is kind of vague.

Number 1: If each piece of paper counts as different, then it is true that they each have 5 choices, so the answer would be 5^125 as you said.

Number 2: Another possibility is that it is asking how many ways can you distribute 125 pages into 5 printers, which you would then use stars and bars with 125 stars and 4 bars to get 129 C 4.

Comment: Stars and bars?

Comment: Stars and bars is a method to distribute indistinguishable objects into distinguishable groups. Basically you have an amount of "stars" and you want to separate them using "bars", by putting them in between. Each method of putting the bars in leads to a different outcome. Since you need 4 bars to separate into 5, you have 125 stars and 4 bars, which leads to 129 C 4 ways. Here is an article for more info about it. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)

Comment: After reviewing the literature, it doesn't seem stars and bars apply because page 1 and page 2 being printed on printer 1 is distinguishable from page 1 and page 2 being printed on printer 2. Thanks for the extra info though, it does help illustrate the entire problem space!